# Looping through columns and rows in google sheet to label gmail - google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, label

I'm trying to label gmail threads using sheet columns. The code itself is fine, I have tested using single rows. For example, A2 (MessageID 1) with B2 (Label 1) and I got it to label the gmail threads based on the columns successfully.

However, right now I'm struggling with the loop.

Here's the script

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    
    var range=sheet2.getRange('A2:A');
    var value =range.getValues();

    var range2=sheet2.getRange('B2:B');
    var value2 =range2.getValues();

  var i = 0; //count
  while ( value2[i][0] != "" && value2[i][0] != "#N/A" ) {
    
    let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(value2[i]);
    if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel(value2[i]);

    console.log("Get threads");
    var threads= GmailApp.getThreadById(value[i]);
    console.log("Add label");
    threads.addLabel(label);
    
    
    i++;
  }
return i;
}  
     
}
```

Here's an image of the columns

[image: the columns]

Here's a link to the [testing sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hP9WtcrgUoq_y-WLOozqlm6k7zuXp9gz-sRC0ThcNBk/edit?usp=sharing)

**Problem with the code execution:**

1. If include `return i;`, it only process the first row and doesn't loop through other rows.
2. If remove `return i;` the execution never stops.

---

I've tried to apply other types of loops, it may be because I'm not quite proficient with loops but this is the closest I could get so far.

So is there a solution to this?

Comment: I tried in on my side. I removed the excess `}` and include `Logger.log(value[i]+" "+value2[i]);` inside the `while-loop`. All the rows where shown in the logs

Comment: @RonM Yes. I did not notice that at all T^T . I've removed it and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i++` is inside an `if` statement - so it may never get incremented, if the label it is handling already exists.

I assume you should have only the one statement inside that `if()`:

```js
if (!label) {
  label = GmailApp.createLabel(value2[i]);
}
```

And then you need to delete the extra `}` lower down in your code.

Also, the return statement is redundant.

It's probably easier to see what is going on if the code is indented correctly.

Comment: I feel so silly right now, such careless mistake. I'll make sure to pay more attention to the code indentation next time. I've checked `}` many times and thought it was enough since there was no error on that.. didn't notice the positions at all T^T. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - we have all done that. You will be pointing it out to other people, soon enough :-)